# How to make logo div stay beneath all other divs?

Tags: html, css

My site has 5 divs represented by green boxes. There should be only 3 divs per row. The following demo shows the logo "Demo" appearing next to the 5th div (in the bottom-right).  [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JopYZp)

Instead I'd like it to be placed under all the content, like this

[image: Screenshot]

The logo resides within a div called "logospace"

```
<div id="logospace">
<center><img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/demo-sign-d-letter-blocks-forming-isolated-white-background-36021240.jpg"></center>
</div>
```

and its CSS now is just:

```
#logospace{
   margin-top:10%;
}
```

Probably super easy fix, but I can't find a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Watching your code: a p element should not contain other block elements including p itself http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1 (`p.vignette` in `p.price`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure your logo clears the floated elements, using `clear`:

```
#logospace{
   clear: both;
   margin-top:10%;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNLVmN)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rock solid clear method if you are wanting to serve your page to older browsers.

```
/*Clear Fix*/
.cf:before, .cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/* For IE 6/7 only */
.cf {
 *zoom: 1;
}
```

After adding this CSS to your sheet you div would look like this.

```
<div id="logospace cf">
<center><img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/demo-sign-d-letter-blocks-forming-isolated-white-background-36021240.jpg"></center>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian,  I went with the other answer but appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Normally using `clear:both` is your best bet, but this trick works too.

```
#logospace{
   margin-top:10%;
   width:100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks skribe, I went with the other answer but appreciate your help